# embed stackoverflow user status

Tags: discussion, questions

I see that there are people that embed their stack overflow status in their blog. Something like this:

[image]

Where can I get a high resolution picture of this?

Answer (score 7):

Look on your profile page, on the lower set of tabs, under flair.

Answer (score 3):

Phil's answer is the "correct" one by StackOverflow standards. But I wanted to mention a better alternative! Use [rchern's awesome SuperCollider StackFlair Generator](https://stackapps.com/q/1567)!!! It's far cooler than the standard flair, because, well, it just is.

Comment: If you're one of the people for whom StackFlair works, use it, and enjoy! If you aren't (sadly, my situation), check out [se-flair](http://stackapps.com/questions/2119/se-flair-html-combined-stackexchange-site-flair).

Comment: @Dori: It doesn't work for you???  **Oy!** We'll get the Beckernator on that right away! ;-)

Comment: [Bug report filed here](https://github.com/rchern/StackFlair/issues/15), btw.